# UIButton with Text Stroke/Outline

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, uibutton

I would like to draw a `UIButton` with text that is using an outline i.e. stroke. So I tried to play around with titleLabel making my own custom label and assigning to `UIButton.titleLabel` which does not work. Someone mentioned I can add `UILabel` on top of `UIButton` but I am not sure this solution is good.

Can someone recommend a stable approach to this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also add a view as subview to your button.
In this view you can place your Label or, if you want, more labels to have e.g. a button with two different formatted textlines.

Comment: This may not be the best solution but I wanted iOS 5 support so could not use answer with NSAttributedString and I also had trouble subclasssing UIButton. UILable I could subclass fine and it works for me.

Answer (score 6):

You can use

```
- (void)setAttributedTitle:(NSAttributedString *)title forState:(UIControlState)state
```

method of `UIButton`.

eg. like this for attributed string

```
NSAttributedString *attributedText =
[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:title
                                       attributes:@{NSStrokeWidthAttributeName: [NSNumber numberWithInt:-6],
                       NSStrokeColorAttributeName: titleBorderColor,
                   NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor whiteColor]}];
```

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention that :)

Comment: Too bad, it looks like a better solution though. I seem to fail with others for now.